# Determining which UIPicker's toolbar button sent a message

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to use multiple UIPickers on a page. I think I've configured almost everything. When I use a UIPicker I add in a a tool bar with a "Cancel" and a "Done" Button.

The toolbars are built using the same function, so it calls the same action when a user taps "Done". A pseudo example flow below.

```
 let pickerData: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
 var picker = UIPickerView()
 let pickerData2: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
 var picker2 = UIPickerView()

 @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  // set up pickers
  setPickerView()
}    

// set the pickerview
func setPickerView(){
    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.delegate = self
    textField.inputView = picker
    textField.inputAccessoryView = initToolBar()
    // second picker
    picker2.dataSource = self
    picker2.delegate = self
    textField2.inputView = picker
    textField2.inputAccessoryView = initToolBar()
}

// build the toolbar for uipicker, so a user can select a value
func initToolBar() -> UIToolbar {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:14.0/255, green:122.0/255, blue:254.0/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    // TODO need to update actions for all buttons
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(pickerDoneAction))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolBar
}

func pickerDoneAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
     /*Here I'm just updating the same textfield when the done button is
       is pressed, I'm not sure how I can get the instance of the picker into this method*/
     let indexPath = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
     textfield.text = data[indexPath]
}

// delegates
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int { return 1 }
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
  if pickerView == picker {
    return pickerData.count
    } else return pickerData2.count
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
  if pickerView == picker {
    return pickerData[row]
  } else return pickerData2[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
  if pickerView == picker {
    textField.text = pickerData[row]
  } else textField2.text = pickerData2[row]
}
```

Is there a way to determine which UIPicker was being used when the done button was clicked, so I could use that instance in my `pickerDoneAction` method and then change the corresponding textfield's value? I tried checking if the textfield was firstResponder and even tried to check the UIPicker itself, but it didn't seem possible. Do I need to change my approach and if so how?

**Update**
I've added in my existing `UIPicikerView` delegate methods.

Just to clarify, I want the value of the `UIPicker` to be assigned to the correct textfield when a user presses "Done", therefore if a user wants to select the very first row from a UIPicker, it gets inserted.

Comment: @downvoter, if you're going to down vote - fine, but it would be more constructive to put it in a comment, so it could be corrected.

Comment: yes, or define pickerview as properties of the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pass down data using `UIView`'s `tag` property:

```
func setPickerView() {
    picker.tag = 1
    textField.inputView = picker
    textField.inputAccessoryView = initToolBar(pickerTag: picker.tag)

    picker2.tag = 2
    textField.inputView = picker2
    textField.inputAccessoryView = initToolBar(pickerTag: picker2.tag)
}

func initToolBar(pickerTag: Int) {
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(pickerDoneAction))
    doneButton.tag = pickerTag
}

func pickerDoneAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    let pickerView: UIPickerView

    switch sender.tag {
    case picker.tag:        pickerView = picker
    case picker2.tag:       pickerView = picker2
    default:                return
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I hadn't gone far enough up the chain to send it across. Your solution was simple and nice ti implement. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can implement the following UIPickerViewDelegate's method:

```
optional func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
            didSelectRow row: Int, 
             inComponent component: Int)
```

where the method is Called by the picker view when the user selects a row in a component and use

```
pickerView
```

(An object representing the picker view requesting the data) to know which pickerview has been used.

Comment: It may also be helpful to add a tag to each `pickerView`, to get a string representation of the selected `pickerView`.

Comment: I should use `didSelectRow` inside my `pickerDoneAction`?

Comment: no, just implement that method above your method "pickerDoneAction"

Comment: @AlessandroChiarotto I already have function in use this in use, but this won't be called when the user presses the "done" button I don't think, I've also update my question to clarify

Comment: Use a new variable in order to store the last pickerview or the last value used by the user and then use this variable when you handel the click of done button

Comment: Can you show me in an example as per the bounty please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing data dynamically with different conditions that you set as data source to pickerview

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to determine which picker it is, but which text field.

In `pickerDoneAction(sender:)`, use `let textField = sender.superview.superview`, where `sender` is the button, `parent` is the toolbar and the toolbar's `parent` is the text field. Then you fill it with `pickerData[0]`.

Another way to achieve the same goal is to use `UITextFieldDelegate`'s method `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)`. When the text field ends editing, insert the default value there.

Comment: When I try this, I get a compilation error, UIBarButtonItem has no member parent

Comment: Sorry, it should be `superview` instead of `parrent`. Edited.

Comment: I get no member superview now for UIBarButtonItem

Comment: Well, looks like this won't work then. See par's answer, that's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

```
let pickerData: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
 var picker = UIPickerView()
 let pickerData2: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
 var picker2 = UIPickerView() // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
 var userPicker:UIPickerView?

 @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

.....
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
  userPicker = pickerView // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
  if pickerView == picker {
    return pickerData[row]
  } else return pickerData2[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
  userPicker = pickerView // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
  if pickerView == picker {
    textField.text = pickerData[row]
  } else textField2.text = pickerData2[row]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check which textfield is in editing state. Do this in your done clicked function. You don't have to add any tags to the pickerView or to the textField.

```
 func pickerDoneAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if textField1.isEditing == true {
        Print("pickerview 1 is selected")
    } else {
        Print("pickerview 2 is selected")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)